# react js: how to format the following data to render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to format the following data to render ?
I have some data comes from apis, but I don't know how to render it

```
let data = [
        {
            type: "Typical",
            tower: "T3",
            floor: "4",
            flat: "B",
            status: ""
        },
        {
            type: "Typical",
            tower: "T5",
            floor: "5",
            flat: "C",
            status: "closed"
        },
        {
            type: "Typical",
            tower: "T7",
            floor: "4",
            flat: "B",
            status: "closed"
        },
        {
            type: "Typical",
            tower: "T4",
            floor: "7",
            flat: "B",
            status: "closed"
        },
        {
            type: "Typical",
            tower: "T2",
            floor: "5",
            flat: "C",
            status: "opening"
        },
    ];
```

I want to output the following text using react js:

```
title: , times: 1
title: closed, times: 3
title: opening, times: 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: what will be format? will it be an array or object?

Comment: just a text
e.g.
<h1>title: , times: 1</h1>

Answer (score 0):

just iterate through your data

```
var results = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (results[data[i].status] != null) results[data[i].status]++;
  else results[data[i].status] = 1;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to process your data into the way you want it. I would do it as follows. Let us assume `data` as the same data you have in question.

```
let data = [{},...];

const res = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  const key = item.status || ' ';
  res[key] = (res[key] || 0) + 1;
});
```

Now `res` will be of format.

```
res = {opening: 1, closed: 3, ' ': 1};
```

Then you can get `keys` from `res` and iterate over it to display your data. Below, we form the required text. You can format it as per your need.

```
const finalResult = Object.keys(res).map((key) => {
 return `title: ${key}, times: ${res[key]}`;
}).join('\n');

console.log('Final result\n' + finalResult);
```

Check the console in [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/marudhupandiyang/pen/qPreBN)

You should get output similar to below
[image: console view]

Comment: when I console.log the res, sometimes can get the object but sometimes can not get.

Comment: You should always get the object bcoz, it is initialized as `const` and as an `object`. If not, then there should be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array of object with status and number of times the status.
Loop through the original object and use `findIndex` to check if the status is already present.If present just update the value

```js
let data = [{
    type: "Typical",
    tower: "T3",
    floor: "4",
    flat: "B",
    status: ""
  },
  {
    type: "Typical",
    tower: "T5",
    floor: "5",
    flat: "C",
    status: "closed"
  },
  {
    type: "Typical",
    tower: "T7",
    floor: "4",
    flat: "B",
    status: "closed"
  },
  {
    type: "Typical",
    tower: "T4",
    floor: "7",
    flat: "B",
    status: "closed"
  },
  {
    type: "Typical",
    tower: "T2",
    floor: "5",
    flat: "C",
    status: "opening"
  },
];

let dataObj = [];
data.forEach(function(item) {
  let getIndex = dataObj.findIndex(function(item2, index) {
    return item2.title === item.status
  })

  if (getIndex === -1) {
    let obj = {};
    obj.title = item.status
    obj.times = 1;
    dataObj.push(obj)
  } else {
    dataObj[getIndex].times = dataObj[getIndex].times + 1;
  }
})
console.log(dataObj)
dataObj.forEach(function(item) {
  for (var keys in item) {
    document.write(keys + ':' + item[keys] + '</br>')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below in your render method.

```
render() {
    let data = 'Your data here';
    let status = ['opening', 'closed', ''];
    return (
       <div>
           {status.map((sta, i) => {

              let count = 0; // Initial count for status

              data.map((st, j) => {
                   if(st.status == sta) {
                       ++count;
                   }
              })

              return (
                  <div key={i}>
                      <span>title: {sta}, times: {count}</span>
                  </div>
              )
           })}
        </div>    
    )
}
```

You can check with the working jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/3ps16j08/2/

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, you will likely want to move the processing outside of render. Below it is shown in render in accordance with your question:

```
render() {
    const processedData = data.reduce((result, next) => {
        const title = `${next.tower} ${next.floor} ${next.flat}`
        const status = next.status
        result[title] = result[title] || { title: title, counts: {} }
        result[title].counts[status] = result[title].counts[status] || 0
        result[title].counts[status]++
        return result
    }, {})

    const elemArray = Object.values(processedData).reduce((result, next) => {
        const counts = Object.entries(next.counts)
        const elems = counts.map(entry => (
            <h1>
                {datum.title}: {datum.counts[entry[0]]}, times: {datum.counts[entry[1]]}
            </h1>
        )
        return result.concat(elems)
    }, [])

   return elemArray
}
```